# how to convert dict with unicode to Chinese character using python

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode

I have some kind of data inside a dict structure like

```
u'content': u'iPad\u6536\u5230\uff0c\u5168\u65b0\u672a\u6fc0\u6d3b\uff0c\u82f9\u679c\u8d28\u91cf\u6ca1\u8bdd\u8bf4\uff0c\u54c1\u8d28\u7b2c\u4e00\uff0c\u5927\u5c0f\u6b63\u597d\uff0c\u643a\u5e26\u5f88\u65b9\u4fbf\uff0c\u8d85\u5927\u5185\u5b58\uff0c\u503c\u5f97\u8d2d\u4e70\uff0c\u9001\u8d27\u8d85\u5feb\uff0c\u65e9\u4e0a\u4e70\u4e0b\u5348\u5230\uff0c\u597d \u5feb \u7701&hellip;&hellip;', u'userClientShow': u'\u6765\u81ea\u4eac\u4e1ciPhone\u5ba2\u6237\u7aef', u'score': 5, u'referenceName': u'Apple iPad mini 4 \u5e73\u677f\u7535\u8111 7.9\u82f1\u5bf8\uff08128G WLAN\u7248/A8\u82af\u7247/Retina\u663e\u793a\u5c4f/Touch ID\u6280\u672f MK9N2CH\uff09\u6df1\u7a7a\u7070\u8272', u'referenceType': u'Product', u'isMobile': True, u'status': 1, u'userLevelName': u'\u94bb\u77f3\u4f1a\u5458', u'userImgFlag': 1, u'userLevelId': u'105', u'productSize': u'WIFI\u7248128G', u'orderId': 0, u'recommend': True, u'discussionId': 205415997,
```

This is just some part of it. I want to parse the data and get the specific part I want. But the data is in unicode format and I wonder how could I convert the unicode value in dict structure to Chinese format.

Comment: If you want to see Chinese characters in your `repr` strings instead of escape sequences like `\u6536`, then switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'chinese format'. When you print the dictionary, the strings are displayed as a sequence of unicode code-points (because that's what `unicode.__repr__` returns).

It's already chinese text.

```
print yourdictionary['content']
```

will display chinese characters. I cannot paste the output because when I copy-paste it the site thinks it is spam.

Comment: Then I wonder how to save data with Chinese format. Cause when I try to save data, it just stored with unicode format

Comment: @PeterTsung you keep talking about "chinese format", but there is no such thing. You can either have a unicode object which is a series of unicode code points, or you can encode the data with an encoding (UTF-8, for example), which gives you a sequence of bytes.